# deploying js with python and spacy lib

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, deployment, spacy

I have never setup things this way, I got it running locally but have no clue how I should have do it when I deploy it into an `ec2 server`

I have a `node app` running already in `ec2 server` but recently I have added `spaCy` into one of my api.

The basic logic is calling the api which runs node and part of the js script uses `spawn` to process the `proc.py` file and do some calculation with outputs.

I have tried the following below to setup on my server but of course it failed when calling the api

my original node app is in `/var/www/myApp`

I used `sudo apt install virtualenv` then inside my `/var/www/myApp` I ran the command `virtualenv venv` which creates the virtual environment...

I did a `source venv/bin/activate` to get into the `virtual environment`

Then I started running the commands to install `spacy` mentioned in the `spacy documentation` https://github.com/explosion/spaCy

used this command to install `pip install -U spacy` and `python -m spacy download en`

Then I ran `python -m spacy validate` to see if spacy is installed which I got

```
Installed models (spaCy v2.0.11)
    /var/www/myApp/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spacy

    TYPE        NAME                  MODEL                 VERSION                                   
    package     en-core-web-sm        en_core_web_sm        2.0.0    ✔      
    link        en                    en_core_web_sm        2.0.0    ✔
```

which I believe this means the installation is a success.

But after this, I am not sure what I should do to continue.

I tried running my api but getting this as an error message `"err": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n"`

I would believe the `spacy` module is not being called that's why I am getting this error but I am not sure what I should do to get this working.

Would really appreciate for any help, thanks in advance for any advices.

EDIT:

my `proc.py` code is below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import json
    import spacy

    nlp = spacy.load('en')
    text = sys.argv[1]
    doc = nlp(text)

    all_noun_tokens = [ token.lemma_ for token in doc
            if (token.pos_ == 'PROPN'
                or token.pos_ == 'NOUN'
                or token.tag_ == 'NN'
                or token.tag_ == 'NNP') ]

    print(json.dumps(all_noun_tokens))
```

P.S. I am wondering if there's any config that I need to do in order for my app to find where the `virtuanenv` is so it can detect the `spacy` module?

Comment: The spaCy installation definitely looks successful and it sounds like you did everything correctly here. Could you post the actual code you're running as part of your API, e.g. what's done in `proc.py`? That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: @InesMontani added the `proc.py` code, but it runs perfectly locally though so I am wondering if there's anything I am missing for `virtualenv` config

Comment: Yes, definitely check that you're running `proc.py` in the same virtual environment (and that it's activated correctly). I don't know how the rest of your app works – but you might actually find it easier to wrap the spaCy code in a simple REST API that your Node app can then make requests to. You can find some examples of this in the [`spacy-services`](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-services) repo.

Comment: @InesMontani it might be I am not sure where and how I can setup the `virtualenv` config correct, I just know how to install and run it on the server as if it is local but I know there should be some config that I tried googling but having hard time not sure how to google it.  Do you have any idea for examples?